# Youtube custom play button

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

it is possible to create a button to play and pause the youtube video when using the youtube script, i mean this

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="853" height="510" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LVcXdMB1_YA?rel=0&amp;hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i'm using this to load the video, but i would like to have for example a link, saying "Play Video", and when the user click the link, the video start to play, all i've tried ends up in nothing, i even think that it is no way to do this, but to be sure, i came here to SO.